# Hazelcast UI. Is there any Hazelcast UI endpoint which shows the metrics of the server

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have recently embedded Hazelcast distribution cache into my application and the performance is quiet good. Out of interest I would like to see the data that is stored in the Hazelcast server and any statistics of the server. Is there an UI end-point to see the metrics of the server?

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Management/Getting_Member_Statistics/Map_Statistics.html shall help you.

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you. But the servers are already running, I'm looking for an UI end point so I can see the metrics without touching the code again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 options.

(1) You can use the JMX beans that expose metrics and then use a GUI like VisualVM to view...

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Management/Monitoring_with_JMX.html

(2) For up to 2 members in a cluster you can use the Hazelcast Management Centre which provide visual metrics/graphs etc...

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.8.4/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy Hazelcast management center jar into your tomcat or any web server which is accessible to your Hazelcast application server.

https://download.hazelcast.com/management-center/management-center-3.8.4.zip

Then in code provide below configuration.

```
// Create Hazelcast configuration with management-center enabled.
Config config = new Config("instanceOne");
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
// Pass the URL where you deployed management-center jar
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://hostname:8080/mancenter");
//create hazelcast instance with config object.
HazelcastInstance instanceOne = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are very informative but it's very confusing for someone like me who is new to JMX as well as Hazelcast. Were you able to figure this out and view your Hazelcast cache? I have a spring-boot application that uses Hazelcast and after following the link from the answer above, I installed and started Hazecast management-center. But I can't really figure out how to connect my application with this management-center thing. Any step-by-step help?